ODBC: ERROR [HY000] importing data to Excel
I have an ODBC database I can connect to and navigate to correct folder and table.  Table has over 200,000 entries and I only want to pull in 258 of them. The column in the table is called WWID and it is format of 12345678.  I am wanting to write a SQL query on my connection to save having it pull all the data into the Power Query in Excel.  When I try to use a SQL statement it gives me the error:

ODBC: ERROR [HY000] ERROR: Syntax error: Exception parsing query near 'WorkerSnapshotPublic'
java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Exception parsing query near 'WorkerSnapshotPublic';
Error while executing the query

Table name is correct, column name is correct.  Perhaps Data type is incorrect but not sure how to tell.
I gave it the SQL Command:
SELECT *
FROM WorkerSnapshotPublic
WHERE WWID IN ('12345678');

I wanted to be able to have it read in a list of 258 WWID from a CSV but want to start with how to get the command to work.

1.are you able to pull other. tables from the same database?
2.if yes can you check by pulling any other column ?
3.which odbc driver you are using?
